# What are the plastic connectors called (for glassware)?

Tags: equipment

I can't remember for the life of me, and google isn't making it easy. e.g. the things labeled 24/40 etc., as in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those are called **Keck Clips**. 24/40 is the size of the joint.

Comment: in mm, I guess?

Comment: @khaverim *very* likely, as it is a Swiss idea (https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=4442572A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=&date=19840417&DB=&locale=#)

Comment: Yes more or less, it's not the exact value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_glass_joint describes the different types and the german wikipedia page actually shows the biggest diameter mm values. It's all in ISO 383

Answer (score 6):

They are called Keck clamps.

Here's a link to the page for ChemGlass: http://www.chemglass.com/product_view.asp?pnr=CG-145

Comment: There are versions in metal, too; like https://www.vaporbrothers.com/Metal-Keck-Clip-19mm_ProductID_8766

Comment: They are clips not clamps

Comment: @JamesDealon Please direct your comment to ChemGlass. I don't have strong feelings about the name. The important part is "Keck."

Answer (score 3):

The clips are named after Hermann Keck - Chemistry World's Classic Kit columnist, Andrea Sella, spoke to him to get the story of the invention before he died a few years ago. https://www.chemistryworld.com/opinion/classic-kit-keck-clip/3004921.article